# Как сделать анимацию в qml из разных картинок?

Tags: qt, анимация, qml

Разбираюсь сейчас с анимацией в qml и нашел достаточно много гайдов которые помогают делать анимацию но только с помощью одной длинной картинки которая включает себя много маленьких по типу такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот какой код я использую для создания анимация из такой картинки:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    AnimatedSprite {
        id: animSprite
        width: 100
        height:100

        y: 100

        // Источник, спрайтовая картинка
        source: "player_animation.png"
        frameCount: 8  // Количество кадров
        frameWidth: 46  // Ширина фрейма
        frameHeight: 50 // Высота фрейма
        frameSync: true // Синхронизация
        frameRate: 10

    }


    NumberAnimation {
        target: animSprite
        property: "x"
       from: -100
       to: 800
       duration: 8000
       loops: Animation.Infinite
       running: true
    }

}
```

Но очень много сайтов с которых надо покупать/скачивать спрайты, предоставляют просто набор скажем из пяти просто картинок с анимацией персонажа не слитые в одну. Скажем просто несколько картинок которые описывают одну анимацию. Скажите есть ли нормальный способ сделать анимацию из скажем пяти картинок (как в некоторых других языках просто что то типо цикла который не занимает основной поток и на место спрайта по очереди встают эти разные картинки)? Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, лучшим способом в вашем случае будет сконвертировать изображения в .gif формат и использовать [`AnimatedImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animatedimage.html) для отображения.